# How to calculate the amount of energy in joules/s that gas oven uses?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I know there may be missing information, but my question is really simple and yet I haven't found an answer to it. To make things easy, let's assume we have a $40×40×40$ cm oven that we want to keep its temperature at $200$ degrees Celsius using natural gas. How much energy per second is consumed to achieve this?

Comment: Too much info missing

Comment: @Awesome What else do I need to know to be able to calculate this ?

Comment: What type of heat losses are you considering. I assume only conduction. For that you need outer temperature and conductivity and dimensions of walls of your oven. Could you describe your oven? The term may have different meanings in different regions.

Comment: Just a normal stove oven with dimensions stated in original post. And yes, assume conduction is the only type of heat loss.

Comment: You have to specify their thickness and other things I mentioned

Comment: @Awesome Conduction is probably not enough, natural convection and radiation are significant heat losses for these kind of problems too.

Comment: And clearly the oven is not a closed system, fresh air is entering to provide oxygen for combustion. It really is a difficult problem to do right. The easy way is to watch your gas meter to get a volumetric flow rate, get the composition from your utility company and calc. power input rather than output.